# Please consider supporting arXiv trackbacks on the mother Meta

Tags: discussion, feature-request

One long-standing feature requests for the Stack Exchange engine is the implementation of *trackbacks* for mentions of the arXiv on Stack Exchange sites. In general, if you have a blog and you blog about an arXiv eprint, you can send the arXiv a specially crafted http message, and then your blog gets listed on a page of the form

```
http://arXiv.org/tb/paper-id
```

that lists a bunch of internet locations that discuss the eprint. Some more examples of how this works:

> - *Example:* [Here](http://arxiv.org/tb/0905.2658) is a list of trackbacks to the arXiv preprint [arXiv:0905.2658](http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2658) from various blogs. My feature-request is that if a future SE post mentions an arXiv number, say, [arXiv:0905.2658](http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2658), then a trackback is automatically sent to the arXiv.org who then adds the SE post to the [trackback list](http://arxiv.org/tb/0905.2658).
> - *Example:* [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/30320/2451) SE answer mentions the arXiv preprint [arXiv:0707.2895](http://arxiv.org/abs/0707.2895). With trackbacks to the arXiv, it would be possible to see on the corresponding [trackback list](http://arxiv.org/tb/0707.2895) that this preprint is mentioned on SE.
> - *More Examples:* ([SE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9727/2451), [arXiv preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.5222), [trackback list](http://arxiv.org/tb/1103.5222));
>   ([SE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48292/2451), [arXiv preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.0545), [trackback list](http://arxiv.org/tb/1211.0545)).

For recent trackbacks from across the internet to the whole of arXiv, see http://arxiv.org/tb/recent.

The trackback mechanism was implemented and put online on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) in 2013, and it has been ticking along ever since. A feature request was posted at about that time on [Meta Stack Excange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) to enable this across all the science Stack Exchange sites, at

### [Trackbacks from SE to the arXiv.org?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240520/trackbacks-from-se-to-the-arxiv-org)

It has received a lot of love over the years (currently at score 62) but apparently this has not been enough. So: do you think this mechanism should be enabled on network sites? If so, either post an answer here saying Aye, or go show that feature-request some (more) love.

Comment: I would recommend posting this on the SE-level Meta, rather than here, where it will be much less visible.

Comment: @aeismail That's... sort of the point of this question. As the question body and title indicate, this *has* been posted on [meta.se]. This is a request for support from this community to that feature request.